# What is the name for this round metal drain cover?

Tags: plumbing, water

Rainwater drains from an acre uphill from us into an underground system that has been in place for 50 years.  It works fine, except that the 16-inch round metal cover for the drain has rusted through.  What is the name of this round piece, almost like a city sewer cover, but smaller and thinner?  Without the right name, it's hard to find a replacement.  Any suggestions on what it might be called?

Comment: A picture is always helpful.

Comment: I would say "I need a 16" round outdoor iron drain cover."

Answer (score 2):

Sump cover. Technically what you have is a Rainwater Collection Cistern, so Cistern cover, Cistern access cover or Cistern hatch cover all would apply.